# Angular $routeProvider resolve not making data immediately available to components controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a route provider which requiring that some data be resolved prior to performing the route as seen here:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    template: '<home message="$resolve.getMessage"></home>',
    resolve: {
        getMessage: getMessage
    }
})
```

the data is then passed to my home component and a binding is made to allow access it from the controller as seen here:

```
.component('home', {
    templateUrl: '/app/content/home.component.html',
    bindings: {
        message: '='
    },
    controller: 'HomeController'
});
```

When attempting to immediate access the data from message when the controller loads(which I was under the impression that the controller doesn't execute its code till the resolve function in the routeProvider resolves...) I am coming up with a undefined variable.

```
function HomeController() {
    var vm = this;
    console.log(vm.message); //undefined
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(vm.message); //properly defined
    }, 1000);
}
```

The code in the timeout function executes with the data properly. I was again under the impression that the Controller code wasn't called/executed until the data from the resolve promise had been received. I feel I must be making a mistake with that logic.

Can anyone provide information on why data is delayed to the components controller even when using resolve?

Thanks!

Comment: whats the point of bindings if you still have to inject it into controller?

Comment: which version of angular you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using angular 1.6 version in which bindings becomes undefined.

You've to use `$onInit` method to access the bindings.

```
function HomeController() {
    var vm = this;
    console.log(vm.message); //undefined
    vm.$onInit = function(){
    // Angular 1.6 onwards, bindings will only be accessible in $onInit method
    console.log(vm.message);  // binding value after resolve
    };
}
```

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

> $onInit() - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an
>   element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and
>   before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this
>   element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your
>   controller.

Comment: This is perfect, this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Works as expected. vm.$onInit = function() { console.log(vm.message) }

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling `$resolve`. You should not call it in your html.

Define a controller which is using service with resolve:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    template: '<home message="homeMessage"></home>',
    controller : 'MyRouteController',
    resolve: {
        message : getMessage
        //getMessage can be async
    }
})


app.controller("MyRouteController", function ($scope, message) {
    $scope.homeMessage = message;
});
```

And now you can send it to your component.

**INFO**

I suggest use templateUrl for this situations.

If your route is "/home" then name it like:

```
controller : HomeController
templateUrl : 'home.html'
```

If you want to use a component to show home message then name it like:

```
component : home-message.component.js
controller : HomeMessageController
templateUrl : 'home-message.html'
```

Don't forget : Route controllers and component controllers are different!

Comment: I implemented this solution but still the HomeController doesn't have access when it initially runs. It seems like what I am looking for is how to keep a components controller from executing until the route resolve is complete. +1ing as it shows a controller having immediate access to the resolved data.

Comment: @BrentAureli If you are using resolve; Controller have to wait message data. Can you show your getMessage function.

Comment: @BrentAureli And don't use common names in your bindings. change 'message' binding to 'myMessage' and us it in html my-message

Comment: I understand controllers have to wait for data from resolve. Exagerated Example of whats happening: User is on about page -> clicks on home button -> The route doesn't change to the home template for 5 seconds as the promise is being fulfilled(which is good and what I intend, to delay showing a template till its entire data is avaliable) -> However the components controller started executing 5 seconds ago and the data is just getting here. I dont want the components controller to execute till the template loads(and presumably after the data has arrived).

Comment: function getMessage(messagefactory) {
        return messagefactory.getMessage();
    }

This is just a $http call that comes back as a promise.